# Python time complexity of graph drawing function

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I am trying to calculate the time complexity of this graph drawing function. I think the time complexity is O(N^2) because of the 2 for-loops in drap_graph but the check_letters function makes me unsure.

Anyone who can help me understand how to calculate it?

```
def check_letters(word1, word2):
    if(word1 == word2):
        return False
    matches = [] 
    letters = word1[-4:]
    for char in letters:
        if char in word2:
            matches.append(char)

    result =  all(elem in matches for elem in letters)
    matches = None
    return result

def draw_graph(words):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    G.add_nodes_from(words)

    for word1 in words:
        for word2 in words: 
            if(check_letters(word1, word2)):
                G.add_edge(word1, word2)
    nx.draw_networkx(G)
    return G

draw_graph(words)
```

Edit: Every word is 5 letters.

Comment: if the length of words has a maximum value, it is `O(n^2)`, otherwise you need to consider complexity of `check_letters` as well

Comment: You can't disregard the size of each word in the list, since `check_letters` iterates over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computational complexity is the answer to the question "How does runtime scale with the size of the input?".

Here, in isolation, your `draw_graph()` is `O(n^2)`, because

1. It iterates through each part of the input (`n`)
2. *for each of those*, it iterates *again* through each part of the input (`n`)

Because the second event is *dependent on the first*, we multiply: `n * n = n^2`. As the number of words in `words` increases linearly, the runtime of the function increases quadratically.

In practice, we can mostly ignore `check_letters()`'s runtime when analyzing `draw_graph()`, because over time the average size of a word will even out, and we can consider it a constant-time operation relative to `draw_graph()`.

Comment: agree with above if the author implies average (theta) time complexity, not the worst case (big-Oh).

Comment: Theta does not mean "average" and O does not mean "worst case".